# How to add CoreUI to rails (+ React) app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, core-ui

I want add the CoreUI package to my rails (with React) application.
But i don't know how to do. I know there is a coreui gem but this gem has the 1.0.1 version of coreui...

Maybe just a `npm install @coreui/coreui` install it ? I don't know..

I just want to add the coreui react template into my rails app..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its mentioned on [Core UI official docs](https://coreui.io/docs/getting-started/introduction/)....

```
=====add css=====

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css">


=======add js========

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/js/coreui.min.js"></script>


======npm install -> get the react packages and functions=======

npm install @coreui/coreui
```